# How to convert a list into string and this string back to the initial list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following issue with Python and I was wondering if there is a direct way to deal with it (using a specific function which I am not aware of, etc.).

I have a list with different types of inputs (integer, string, etc.). I transform the list into a string using the `str()` function. Now the type of the variable is a string. I do some processing with this string and then I want to transform the string back into the initial list with the initial variable types it had (integer, string, etc.).

Here is an illustration:

```
             list = [1,'house',3]
             print(type(list))  # gives <class list>
             print(type(list[0])) # gives <type int>
             print(type(list[1])) # gives <type str>

             string = str(list)
             print(type(string)) # gives <type string>
             ... # use this string to process data


            # convert the string into the initial list
             ? ?
```

I thought maybe I could in the beginning iterate my list and store the type of its attributes in a list (`list_b`). Later when I convert the string to a list I will explode the string and convert the strings to the variable types corresponding to the `list_b`.

I was wondering if there is a more straight forward way than this?

Comment: While converting, do you want the numbers t obe int again or should they stay string?

Comment: Why on earth are you processing the list as a string? As it only contains built-in Python objects you can use `ast.literal_eval` on it, but it seems likely you could be doing this a completely different way.

Comment: Vincent they have to become strings again.

Comment: jonrsharpe I use a gis library which requires the input in such a form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert a string into a Python object.

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "[1, 'house', 3]"
l = literal_eval(s)
print(l)
# [1, 'house', 3]
```

Note that, as per the docs linked above, the string can only be formed of strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good use case for Python's 'json' module, as it can transform lists and dictionaries into JSON (which is a string format) and vice versa.

So for example:

```
import json
x = [1,2,3]
y = json.dumps(x) # => '[1, 2, 3]'
z = json.loads(y) # => [1,2,3]
```

This only works with simple data structures (dict, list, tuple, str, int, long, float, boolean, and None) (more information on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders))

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) answer if your list will contain other kinds of objects that you want to make serializable.